# How can I stop ckeditor from adding <p>&nbsp;</p> in front of pasted word content?

Tags: 7, nodes, wysiwyg

When I paste from word using the word clipboard button I get a blank paragraph inserted before the word content.

Can anyone tell me the way to prevent or fix this?

Comment: On tablet, or I would search, but this was asked and answered recently. Pretty sure module us called Empty Paragraph Killer.

Comment: I found this module but I need to be able to add empty paragraphs elsewhere, just not before the pasted content so it wasn't suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to ckeditor 4 solved this issue for me. I am using wysiwyg 7.x-2.2 and CKEditor 4.0.0.769.

Comment: We have a bunch of custom styles etc setup on our ckeditor, do you know if the upgrade process is painless in this regard?

Comment: @dibs Upgrading to CKEditor 4 is pretty straight-forward if you're just defining custom styles. Custom buttons will take more work, depending on how complex they are.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the patch available at:

https://drupal.org/node/550428#comment-7107518

Haven't tried it yet myself, but will tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

I added

config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

to the ckeditor settings, seems to work.